# I don't understand convolution, and I would love to see some worked examples

Tags: signal, signal-processing

I'm trying to get ahead on my classes for the school year and decided to start with [Alan Oppenheim's Signals and Systems](https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PL41692B571DD0AF9B) course. I'm already very stuck on how to convolve two signals. I have some specific examples from his textbook that I would love to see worked in order to get a better understanding.

[image]

The answer I get is different from the answer the book gives. I tried to graph both of these, and then shift h[n] through x[n] and calculate each point. However, this does not give the book's result of

[image]

Secondly I don't understand this problem

[image]

Any explanations or clues to understanding would be appreciated. I've been watching different videos and searching around and something just isn't clicking.

Below is my attempt to solve the first. I only had blue and black ink for the graphs, and it's not easy to see the different between the h[n] and x[n] graphs.

[image]
[image]

Comment: "*The answer **I** get is different from the answer the book gives*", it's always better if you show us *your attempt* so we can see *exactly* where things went wrong. Then we'll be able to see/give exactly what kind of help you need to get to the correct answer. - Also, is it the mathematical part about convolution that you have trouble with? Or is it the entire meaning of convolution, like what it is and why it's used?

Comment: https://sites.google.com/site/butwhymath/m/convolution

Comment: Show your complete working/solution - as Harry asked you earlier - then people may help you.

Comment: @BeB00 Woaw. I'm fairly knowledgeable about what convolution is (1D), but that site confused me with 2D convolution.

Comment: Late, but maybe [still relevant](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/368372/95619)? For my part, the visualisation of the convolution didn't make much sense compared to the multiplication algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

First off, visualizing how these this function works graphically can be a big help. The first function is 'slid' past the second function, the area of the two defines the height of the third function

[image]
Source Wikipedia: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/97/Convolution_Animation_%28Boxcar%29.gif

Hint:
Sometimes its best to draw the functions, a dirac delta function times a dirac delta function is dirac delta function (and dirac delta functions simply copy whatever function they are convoluted with)

[image]